# How to make chrome devtools to recognise moment.js

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, momentjs

I am working on `ionic2` project. I have just start using `moment.js` but I have a weird issue.
I have installed in via npm: `npm install moment -S`.

Then I have used it in my code:

```
import moment from 'moment'
...
let x = moment()
debugger
```

On the console I get this funny issue:

```
> x
< Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, _d: Wed Jun 27 2018 12:06:23, …}
> y = moment()
< VM770:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at eval (eval at Phase (phase.ts:13), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at new Phase (phase.ts:13)
    at new Stage (stage.ts:10)
    at new HomePage (home.ts:39)
    at createClass (core.es5.js:10795)
    at createDirectiveInstance (core.es5.js:10621)
    at createViewNodes (core.es5.js:11971)
    at createRootView (core.es5.js:11876)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13007)
    at Object.debugCreateRootView [as createRootView] (core.es5.js:12468)
```

Why can't I work with moment within the console?

Comment: Since `moment()` is no longer used in this context ("debugger" is the last line), V8 optimized it away in this context, I guess.

Comment: I have added `let y = moment()` after debugger. Same error.

Comment: If you haven't already, maybe running `node` in the terminal and requiring `moment` in there. This is how I did it.

Comment: Can you post the transpiled version of this code? Maybe it will lead to some answers,

Answer (score 45):

Could fetch it from browser console like this:

```
fetch('https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => eval(text))
```

[image: Then you could use it normally there]

Comment: It does not allow me for some reason: `Refused to connect to 'https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:`

Answer (score 14):

If the library was not imported in the regular form you can't access it; if you want to use `moment()` in the Chrome console you can try to open the [official site](https://momentjs.com/) and then go to the console.

In the console you can write something like

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```